# Mounting two locations with html5fs and different PERSISTENT and TEMPORARY types

Tags: google-nativeclient

I am using nacl_io library in my project. Is it possible to `mount` two locations with `html5fs` file system but different type `PERSISTENT` and `TEMPORARY` at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is supported.

The nacl-spawn library in the naclports repo, which is used to build command line tools, does this by default. It mounts a temporary html5fs at /tmp and persistent ones at /mnt/html5 and /home/user.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I need to use nacl_io not another library.